# Nested for loop functioning

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have trouble understanding nested for loops

```
posts: [
  {
    title: 'lorem',
    comments: [
      {
         content: 'lorem'
         user: 'John'
      },
      ...
    ]
  },

  ...
]
```

My goal here is to get all the comments from a specific user, in all the posts.
Here is how I proceed (I'm using mongoose, I get the user from an auth middleware)

```
const postsList = await Post.find();
var userComments = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < postsList.length; i++) {

     if (postsList[i].comments.length > 0) {

        for (var j = 0; j < postsList[i].comments[j].length; i++)

          if (postsList[i].comments[j].user == req.user.id) {
            userComments.push(comments[j]);
          }
      }
 }
```

When I try this, I get a `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I think my error is in the second for loop, but I can't get why. Any help please?

Comment: It should probably be `postsList[i].comments.length` without the `[j]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark Meyer in the comments is correct.

`comments` is an array inside of each `post` object. `comments[j]`  would refer to an element inside the comments array. `comments[j].length` doesn't make sense because in order to run your nested `j` for loop, which iterates over the `comments` array, you want the length of the `comments` array, not the length of one of its elements.

Here's the line that needs to be fixed:

```
const postsList = await Post.find();
var userComments = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < postsList.length; i++) {

     if (postsList[i].comments.length > 0) {

       // for (var j = 0; j < postsList[i].comments[j].length; i++)
       // fixed version below
        for (var j = 0; j < postsList[i].comments.length; i++)


          if (postsList[i].comments[j].user == req.user.id) {
            userComments.push(comments[j]);
          }
      }
 }
```